Why does GeoServer convert negative values in an "8-bit signed" type raster to positive numbers?
I have a single-band 8-bit signed dataset created in ArcGIS Pro, and the raster information is as follows:


When I load the data into QGIS, issues arise with the negative value areas at small scales, where negatives are incorrectly transformed into positives (this issue is resolved after rebuilding the data pyramid in QGIS). At larger scales, the raster values appear correctly. In this context, QGIS identifies the data as a 16-bit signed type.
small scales
big scales
QGIS Raster info
Using the gdalinfo tool, I obtained the following metadata for the raster, which is identified as int8.

When publishing the data as a WMS service in GeoServer, it recognizes the data as Unsigned 8 bits type, and during display, the "negative regions" are incorrectly rendered as positive values.


I am curious as to why this phenomenon occurs in QGIS – the misinterpretation of the data at small scales before pyramid rebuilding. Furthermore, I would like to understand why GeoServer is recognizing the data as Unsigned 8 bits and subsequently displaying negative regions as positive. Lastly, what is the correct approach to publish data of a Signed 8 bits type to ensure accurate representation?

For me is looks like GeoServer does not support signed 8 bit data type correctly. A workaround is to convert data into unsigned 8 bit.
gdal_translate -ot byte -co tiled=yes -co compress=deflate -scale -128 127 0 256 int8.tif byte.tif


Okay, so it seems that Geoserver does not support 8-bit signed data. I'm a bit puzzled by this because 8-bit signed data can significantly reduce the volume of data, especially for normalized remote sensing products where an 8-bit signed type can save a substantial amount of storage space. I'm curious about the initial design considerations behind GDAL and Geoserver – whether there were factors I'm not considering that made supporting 8-bit signed data types unfeasible or inefficient.

GDAL has supported signed 8-bit data for ages with a bit special way. Now the support is more straight forward https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc87_signed_int8.html. Your GDAL version seems to be a recent one because gdalinfo showed datatype as Int8. About the signed 8-bit support in GeoServer and GeoTools I would ask from their own mailing lists.

Alright, I understand now. I will verify this with the relevant technical support and share the results with everyone later.
